# MS Excel: Search, Find and Extract Specific Text Cell containing text string

Tags: string, text, find, excel-formula

Although, I've seen relatively similar or close postings

Using MS Excel MS Excel 2010, I would like to be able to search Cell Range (Column A1:A25), to find if specific text within Cell String (Column C2) is a match in Cell Range (A1:A26) and then Output the corresponding matching Keyword results found in same or adjacent cell.  If matching text is not found then display "No Match Found"

Although the sample formula shown below that I'm using does work, but only indicates it found or did not find word within Cell Range  I need for it to return the actual matching Keyword text found versus "FOUND" OR "NOT FOUND".

=IF(SUM(IFERROR(FIND(A1:A26,C2),0))>0, "FOUND", "NOT FOUND")

Example:

Cell String contains the following text in Cell C2:

"I found a lost German Sheppard in my backyard on yesterday"

Keyword Search Words: Column A1:A26
TYPES OF DOGS
Affenpinscher
Afghan Hound
Airedale Terrier
Akita
Alaskan Malamute
American Foxhound
American Staffordshire Terrier
American Water Spaniel
Anatolian Shepherd
French Bulldog
German Pinscher
German Shepherd
German Shorthaired Pointer
German Wirehaired Pointer
Giant Schnauzer
Glen of Imaal Terrier
Golden Retriever
Gordon Setter
Great Dane
Greater Swiss Mountain
Great Pyrenees
Greyhound
Harrier
Irish Setter
Irish Terrier

The Returned and displayed results/answer = German Sheppard

Please let me know if this possible, as I would greatly appreciate any assistance to resolving my question.

Miaka3

Comment: The match you specify doesn't match up ("Sheppard" vs "Shepherd")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are searching column A for a string(s) in column C type this array formula in B:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$6,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($C$2:$C$6,A2)),-1,1)*(ROW($C$2:$C$6)-ROW($C$2)+1))), "None")
```

You can see here that I have a search list of multiple characters/strings in `C2` through `C6`.  If one of the search strings is found, it will be listed in column B, otherwise it will display `"None"`.

[image]

The key to this working is copy the above formula into cel B2 and while you are still in edit mode pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` instead of just `Enter` like usual.  You will know it works correctly if you see the addition of { and } in the formula once you hit the three key combination.  After that you can copy the formula down through A25 or wherever you need.

Note you can make your Search List longer or shorter as needed, just make sure to update your formula to reflect the range.  You will want to fill in all of you dog breeds in Column C and change every `$C$2:$C$6` in the formula to equal your search list range.  And, remember, any change to the array formula requires `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to work properly.

Comment: Mitch, I would like to thank you for your excellent reply in assisting me with the Search and Return value in a text string.  I'm new to the site, but I must admit, I'm overwhelmingly impressed with the responsiveness, accuracy and demonstration to replicate the problem to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what Excel was designed for, but you can accomplish it with a helper column.  Insert a new column at B (this will move C2 to D2).  Then paste this formula into B2:

`=IF(ISERROR(FIND(A2,D$2)),"",A2)`

Fill down that formula until A27 (you said A26, but your example went to A27 if you include the header "TYPE OF DOGS").  This will output the breed of the dog only if it is contained within the text in D2.

Finally, go to whatever cell you would like to contain your output, and paste in:

`=CONCATENATE(B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12,B13,B14,B15,B16,B17,B18,B19,B20,B21,B22,B23,B24,B25,B26,B27)`

Comment: Choirbean, I would like to thank you tremendously for providing me with the solutions to my question.  Your provided formula worked perfectly for what I was attempting to achieve.